# How to cleanup postgres temporary tables of recursive query from django/psycopg2

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2, recursive-query

When postgres runs recursive query it creates temporary table for it.
After query is finished, the temporary table remains on disk, until whole program competes.

The program consist of main process and multiprocessing pool of workers, all with separate db connections (and I cannot close connection of main process because it holds iterating data source).

I would like to force postgres to clean up those temporary tables after each query because huge amount of data.

Queries are executed in following way:

```
def process_datum(datum):
   with db.connections['world'].cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT ... from query_function(%s)", (datum.id,))
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
   for row in rows:
        try:
            ...
            A_Model.objects.create(...)
        except db.IntegrityError as e:
            logger.warning("%s: %s", path, e)
```

The `process_datum` is called from worker, the `query_function` is database-side table function implementing recursive query.

P.S
Main queries are:

```
select ... from features limit 1000 offset xxxx;
```

Query function is:

```
with recursive recursion(child_id, parent_id, node_id, path) as (
  select h.child_id, h.parent_id, h.parent_id as node_id, ARRAY[h.parent_id] 
  from hierarchy h
  where h.direct=true and h.child_id=$1
union all
  select h.child_id, h.parent_id, r.node_id, r.path || ARRAY[h.parent_id]
  from recursion r join hierarchy h on h.child_id = r.parent_id
  where h.direct=true and h.parent_id != r.node_id
)
select * from recursion
```

Creating query is like this:

```
insert into hierarchy (parent_id, child_id, direct, path) values (%d, %d, false, %s::bigint[])
```

Comment: *When postgres runs recursive query it creates temporary table for it*. No, it doesn't. It sounds like your framework creates a temp table and launches workers. PostgreSQL's `WITH RECURSIVE` queries do *not* create temp tables.

Comment: Temporary data appears in /var/lib/postgres/.../base/pgsq_tmp -- what else can it be?

Comment: It's not about `recursive` it's about not fitting the memory for calculations. I don't see `ORDER BY`, so probably `CTE` create temporary files as well? @CraigRinger?

Comment: The problem seems to be infinite recursion because of bogus data.
And what's the deal with ORDER BY?

Comment: @qMax That's the temp tablespace, it's used for `TEMPORARY` tables, sort spool files, etc too. I can see that you have now edited to show that there *is* in fact a `WITH RECURSIVE` query, in which case it seems likely that you're dealing with sort spool files etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in infinite recursion due to bogus data (cyclic links).
In my case - recursive query should be fixed to deal with it.

Comment: Anyone else facing this - run postgres with `log_temp_files = 0` to see more on temp file creation.